# How to show Russian text in jQuery dialog title

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How can I show Russian text in a jQuery dialog title? In my case, it shows just this - ???????

Does anybody know why?

Calls showAjaxDialog:

```
$('.ajaxDialog').click(function () {
    ShowAjaxDialog(true, 'Привет Мир', 330, 300, this.href);
    return false;
});
```

AjaxDialog code:

```
function ShowAjaxDialog(isModal, title, width, height, url) {   
    // show a spinner or something via css
    var dialog = $('<div style="display:none" class="ajaxDialogLoading"></div>').appendTo('body');

    // open the dialog
    dialog.dialog({
        // add a close listener to prevent adding multiple divs to the document
        close: function (event, ui) {
            // remove div with all data and events
            dialog.remove();
        },
        width: width,
        height:height,
        modal: isModal,
        title: title
    });

    // load remote content
    dialog.load(
        url,
        //{}, // omit this param object to issue a GET request instead a POST request, otherwise you may provide post parameters within the object
        function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            // remove the loading class
            dialog.removeClass('ajaxDialogLoading');
        }
    );      
    //prevent the browser to follow the link
}
```

Comment: Is this specific to the dialog? Is it displaying correctly on the rest of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mhLc5/

**Link:** http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

**Code:**

```
var $Dialog_div;

function fnOpenDialog() {
    $Dialog_div = $('<div id=\'ThisDialog\'>Hello</div>').prependTo('body');

    $Dialog_div = $('#ThisDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true,
        title: 'Dialog put russian text: Jquery скалы, скалы и StackOverflow',
        modal: true,
        stack: true,
        height: ($(window).height() * 0.95),
        width: ($(window).width() * 0.9),
        buttons: {
            'OK': function() {
                $Dialog_div.dialog('close');
            }    
        }
    });  
}

$('#ClickMe').click(fnOpenDialog);​
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- This is more than likely an Adobe issue where it thinks it should be in the front
     all the time, no matter what. However, it is very annoying that you can't open
     a dialog over a PDF.-->

<body>
    <div id='ClickMe'>Click here!</div>
    <br/>
    <div></div>
    <br/>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks you for help!!! But I found the reason of problem. I have created js file in Visual Studio and file was ANSI, I changed encoding to utf-8 :)

Comment: @Tats_innit I've noticed that majority of your posts contain unneeded greetings and "hope this helps" kind of phrases. As discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950), those kind of phrases are considered clutter. Your questions are easier to follow and read without these extra parts. I've edited some of your posts and don't mind continuing to improve your posts when I have time. It seems like the [Meta consensus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355255/4660897) is that all posts should be improved. Please let me know if this bothers you and if I should stop.

Comment: @TotZam `:)` not at all, I think I came to western world in my teenage, so since my childhood, my Ma emphasized culturally on humbleness, empathy, politeness, respect and honor, which is somehow landed into a bad habit in my writing skills. They at times are hard to get rid of, reminds me of one of the lecture in MIT for AI by Prof. Patrick Henry Winston: where AI is so hard to get right, I learn a lot with many guys around SO, sometimes I find in tech we forget to have culture for inclusiveness. I tend to do that for mutual greeting and saluting everyone. `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit The content in many of your answers does look great, and that why I think they are worth improving! And yes, it does take time and practice to learn how to write in a more textbook style of writing, which is easier for users to learn from, rather than a more informal friendly conversational kind of writing. I've learnt a lot from just reading other well written posts on this site, and copying their styles.

Comment: +1 to your Metapost as well @TotZam `:)` I hope technology evolve one day  that we can have SO Coffee from anywhere in the world `:)`